# unable to connect to my mongodb using visual studio code and pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, visual-studio-code, pymongo

I don't know what is happening with my visual studio code and pymongo, but I am always getting timeouts when I try to connect to my atlas cluster. The funny thing is that I am able to connect in pycharm and in the terminal.
[image: this is the error that I get from VSCode]

[image: pycharm output]

[image: terminal output]

Is there any configuration I must set up to allow VScode in python to connect to my mongo atlas.

Btw, I am also able to connect to my mongo atlas using vscode mongo extension
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that is a problem related with the M1 of apple, I installed an anaconda environment and everything worked like charm